# Post and ajax / php wont talk together?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I have to files, one of them being index.php and the other being survey-result.php.

**Index.php** contains a survey, and a button, and a click on the button should post surveyname and result to survey-result.php. The survey-result.php should then make a mysql connection, and update the database with the result from index, ind the correct survey.

URL example: index.php?id=528E6B678ECE0

Id is a surveyname, that exsists in a mysql database.

**The problem:** There is no connection between the two php files. If I run the survey-result with manual data in result and surveyname, then it will update my database.

Any ideas ? : D

```
<input type='button' value='Create User' onclick='updateSurvey()' />;

    function updateSurvey()
    {

          $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'handlers/survey-result.php',
                    data:
                    {
                        action: 'action',
                        surveyname: <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>,
                        result: 'Test Result',
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(output)
                        {
                            alert("Survey result updated");
                        }

                });
    }
    </script>
```

**handlers/survey-result.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) )
{
    include("include/dbConnect.php");

    $strSQL = " UPDATE surveys
                SET result= . $_POST['result'] .
                WHERE surveyname= . $_POST['surveyname']";

    // The SQL statement is executed
    mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());

    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: missed `}` in `data:{`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) AND XSS attacks. Enjoy having your site pwn3d

Comment: your success callback is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '$.post()' instead of '$.ajax()'.  This will help with formatting it correctly:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/